# JavaScript - create number of divs in loop

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012

I'm a begginer with javaScript. and I want to create number of windows (div) with loop operation only with javaScript.
This is my code:

```
var numOfWindows = 3;

var arrayDiv = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < numOfWindows; i++)
{
   arrayDiv[i] = document.createElement('div');
   arrayDiv[i].id = 'block' + i;
   arrayDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
   arrayDiv[i].className = 'block' + i;
   document.body.appendChild(arrayDiv[i]);
}
```

but I see a blank screen.

Comment: None of your created-`<div>` elements have any content. What would you expect to see?

Comment: press F12 and tell us the error.

Comment: I Expected to see a div with a green background :) but I guess I'm wrong now. I'm ios developer and javaScript is new for me. what should I add to the code? content?

Comment: There is no error. only blank screen...

Comment: There is no error. At all. The *problem* is that the `div` elements have no content and therefore no height, no height means no visibility. Give content, or directly give height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript works perfectly, if you give the created elements some content, or specific dimensions in CSS:

```
var numOfWindows = 3;

var arrayDiv = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < numOfWindows; i++)
{
    arrayDiv[i] = document.createElement('div');
    arrayDiv[i].id = 'block' + i;
    arrayDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    arrayDiv[i].className = 'block' + i;
    // setting the textContent to the 'i' variable:
    arrayDiv[i].textContent = i;
    document.body.appendChild(arrayDiv[i]);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eo2gvaLt/).

Or:

```
var numOfWindows = 3;

var arrayDiv = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < numOfWindows; i++) {
    arrayDiv[i] = document.createElement('div');
    arrayDiv[i].id = 'block' + i;
    arrayDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    arrayDiv[i].className = 'block' + i;

    // setting the class-name of the created elements:    
    arrayDiv[i].className = 'bordered';

    document.body.appendChild(arrayDiv[i]);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eo2gvaLt/1/).

Comment: Thanks ! I'm using your first option :)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give your div a specified width and height.

```
div.style.width = '10px';
div.style.heigt = '10px';
```

Or give it content.